# IF Then Else Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Working on a view that pulls from two table however in one table I need to select either one field or another depending on a third..it's the if else that has me stubbed.

```
 Create view as 
      select
           pens.PartNo,
           pens.Title,
           ranges.weight 
           if(pens.SpeacialOffer = 1 then pens.offer as Price else pens.Price)
      from
           pens, ranges 
      where   
           pens.penrange = ranges.id;
```

If the specialoffer is falged the the view needs to pull in the offer else it needs to pull in the Price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [`CASE` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
CASE
     WHEN condition
     THEN value_a
     ELSE value_b
END
```

So in your case:

```
CASE
     WHEN pens.SpeacialOffer = 1
     THEN pens.offer
     ELSE pens.price
END
```

This replaces the entire column definition in your `SELECT` statement, so the whole view becomes:

```
Create View as 
    Select 
        pens.PartNo,
        pens.Title,
        ranges.weight,
        Case
            When pens.SpeacialOffer = 1
            Then pens.offer
            Else pens.price
        End as Price
    From 
        pens, ranges 
    Where
        pens.penrange = ranges.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE, also converted the query to explicit join instead of implicit join

```
  select pens.PartNo,  
       pens.Title,
       ranges.weight,      
       (Case when  
        pens.SpeacialOffer = 1 then   
        pens.offer else pens.Price 
        end ) as Price 
      FROM pens, 
      JOIn ranges 
      ON pens.penrange = ranges.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
Create view as select
  pens.PartNo,
  pens.Title,
  ranges.weight,
  (pens.SpeacialOffer * pens.offer + (1 - pens.SpeacialOffer) * pens.price) as Price
from
  pens,
  ranges
where
  pens.penrange = ranges.id;
```